# Pass Rest parameter (ellipses dot) to another method in JS

Tags: typescript, spread-syntax, rest-parameters

I need to customize some methods,
for example rollbar has method for log error:

```
public error(...args: Rollbar.LogArgument[]): Rollbar.LogResult;


function myErrorLogger(...args){
   ...
   rollbar.error(args);
   //or 
   rollbar.error.apply(null, args);
}
```

but seems does not work right. and pass args as an array.

Comment: `rollbar.error(...args);`? That `apply` call should also work and is equivalent if `null` is replaced by `rollbar`.

Comment: I try rollbar.error(...args) , but not different,
when do with rollbar.error(args[0], args[1]) work fine.

Comment: What exactly is different?

Comment: it send one array object and got error on rollbar,
for example: 
rollbar.error('Unknown Error Message', ex); // this is OK
myErrorLogger('Unknown Error Message', ex); // this is NOT OK because send ['Unknown Error Message', ex] object and I got error from rollbar